# Guidance to understand Base64 encoding algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm, encoding, base64, bit-shift

I found this algorithm on the net but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly how it works. It encodes an Uint8Array to Base64. I would like to understand especially the sections under the comments "Combine the three bytes into a single integer" and "Use bitmasks to extract 6-bit segments from the triplet". I understood the concept of bit shifting used there, but can't understand what's its purpose in those two sections.

```
function base64ArrayBuffer(bytes) {
  var base64    = ''
  var encodings = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/'

  var byteLength    = bytes.byteLength
  var byteRemainder = byteLength % 3
  var mainLength    = byteLength - byteRemainder

  var a, b, c, d
  var chunk

  // Main loop deals with bytes in chunks of 3
  for (var i = 0; i < mainLength; i = i + 3) {
    // Combine the three bytes into a single integer
    chunk = (bytes[i] << 16) | (bytes[i + 1] << 8) | bytes[i + 2]

    // Use bitmasks to extract 6-bit segments from the triplet
    a = (chunk & 16515072) >> 18 // 16515072 = (2^6 - 1) << 18
    b = (chunk & 258048)   >> 12 // 258048   = (2^6 - 1) << 12
    c = (chunk & 4032)     >>  6 // 4032     = (2^6 - 1) << 6
    d = chunk & 63               // 63       = 2^6 - 1

    // Convert the raw binary segments to the appropriate ASCII encoding
    base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + encodings[d]
  }

  // Deal with the remaining bytes and padding
  if (byteRemainder == 1) {
    chunk = bytes[mainLength]

    a = (chunk & 252) >> 2 // 252 = (2^6 - 1) << 2

    // Set the 4 least significant bits to zero
    b = (chunk & 3)   << 4 // 3   = 2^2 - 1

    base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + '=='
  } else if (byteRemainder == 2) {
    chunk = (bytes[mainLength] << 8) | bytes[mainLength + 1]

    a = (chunk & 64512) >> 10 // 64512 = (2^6 - 1) << 10
    b = (chunk & 1008)  >>  4 // 1008  = (2^6 - 1) << 4

    // Set the 2 least significant bits to zero
    c = (chunk & 15)    <<  2 // 15    = 2^4 - 1

    base64 += encodings[a] + encodings[b] + encodings[c] + '='
  }

  return base64
}
```

Comment: The comment about ASCII encodings is kind of funny because JavaScript uses UTF-16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step takes each group of 3 bytes in the input and combines them into a 24-bit number. If we call them `x = bytes[i]`, `y = bytes[i+1]`, and `z = bytes[i+2]`, it uses bit-shifting and bit-OR to create a 24-bit integer whose bits are:

```
xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz
```

Then it extracts these bits in groups of 6 to get 4 numbers. The bits of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` correspond this way:

```
xxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz
aaaaaabbbbbbccccccdddddd
```

Then for each of these 6-bit numbers, it indexes the `encodings` string to get a corresponding character, and concatenates them into the `base64` result string.

At the end there are some special cases to deal with the last 1 or 2 bytes in the input if it wasn't a multiple of 3 bytes long.

Comment: That's a good way for encoding numbers and sending it through a text-based medium, since it gives you a nice compression. With your answer I was able to understand it and envision how to decode that. For those who need to understand bit shifting, playing around with the Windows calculator in the Programmer mode and binaries helps a lot. Thanks Barmar.

Comment: That's precisely what base64 encoding was created for. Most languages have a library function that performs encoding and decoding for you, you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, I found there are somethings implemented for that, but I needed this to be optimized for numbers and also compatible with older browsers. I'm using JavaScript and it looks like functions like btoa, etc., are not supported by older browsers or non-HTML5 ones.